# Fetch a specific socket from sockets list - NestJs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nestjs, backend, real-time

I need to fetch a specific socket from sockets list with Nests , the way I use in the code below, but I don't want to pull all the sockets in to a list then search for the socket in it , is there away to directly search and fetch the required socket instead of using "fetchSockets()" method?

```
 @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server = new Server<ServerToClientEvents, ClientToServerEvents>();

@SubscribeMessage('event')
  async handelInitial(@MessageBody() data: any): Promise<void> {
 
    const array = await this.server.sockets.fetchSockets();
    const sockest = array.find((e)=>e.id==='required socket id')

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `const sockets = await io.in(theSocketId).fetchSockets();` as described here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchsockets

In your Nest app this would look like this: `await this.server.in('socket id').fetchSockets()`.

Comment: Is there a way to search for a socket based on handshake or data, for example, instead of the ID?